# multiple unrelated log files with log4j and commons logging

Tags: java, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I want my app to have 4 log files.  Three of the log files are the typical log4j Info, Warn and Error logs.  The 4th log file is completely unrelated and is used to log some data.

My log4j.properties file looks like this:

```
log4j.threshold=ALL
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, InfoAppender, WarnAppender, ErrorAppender
log4j.DATA_LOGGER=INFO, DataAppender
log4j.additivity.DATA_LOGGER = false

log4j.appender.DataAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DataAppender.File=/app_logs/data.log

log4j.appender.InfoAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.File=/app_logs/info.log

log4j.appender.WarnAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.WarnAppender.File=/app_logs/warn.log

log4j.appender.ErrorAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ErrorAppender.File=/app_logs/error.log
```

And my Java code looks like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(SomeClassInMyApp.class);
private static final Log DATA_LOG = LogFactory.getLog("DATA_LOGGER");

private static void foo() {
    LOG.info("Hello");
    DATA_LOG.info("Some data");
}
```

When I run this, the "Hello" text is correctly written to the info.log file.  But the data.log file is never created or written to.

Why is the DATA_LOG.info("Some data") line not writing to the data.log file, and what code change do I need to make in order for that to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`commons` should work as well, can you try this

```
   import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
   ...
   ...
   Logger log = Logger.getLogger("DATA_LOGGER");
   ...
   ...
   log.info("my data");
```

instead of this

```
   import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
```

---

**Update** Just tested this code works:

**`log4j.properties`**

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, R

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=E:/testroot.log

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DATE} %-5p %c:%L %x - %m%n


##########################################################################
################## Appender for Other Logger  ############################
##########################################################################
log4j.logger.TestLog=DEBUG, cache
log4j.additivity.TestLog=false

log4j.appender.cache=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.cache.File=E:/testcache.log
log4j.appender.cache.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cache.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n
```

**`Test Code`**

```
private static final Logger DATA_LOG = Logger.getLogger("TestLog");
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);

public static final void main(String[] args){
    LOG.error("MSG1");
    DATA_LOG.error("MSG2");
}
```

**`Output`**

```
testroot.log
09 Feb 2011 12:18:29,671 ERROR in.naishe.so.Test:11  - MSG1

testcache.log
09/02/2011 12:18:29 TestLog MSG2
```

Are you missing something?

Comment: Apparently the problem is log4j and not commons-logging.  The behavior is exactly the same when I tried your suggestion of directly invoking log4j instead of using commons-logging.

Comment: @Mike W updated the code. Unsure what's missing in your code.

Comment: Thanks to your working example, I now see the problem.  On line 3 of my log4j.properties, I have "log4j.DATA_LOGGER" but should have had "log4j.logger.DATA_LOGGER".